# Append to queryset object in Django

Tags: django, django-queryset

My Django Model:

```
class Job(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(_('Job Title'),max_length=150, blank=True, default="")
    description = models.CharField(_('Description'), max_length=250, blank=True, default="")
    user = models.ForeignKey('User', verbose_name="User", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I have a queryset of django objects:

```
>>> jobs = Job.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<Job: university>, <Job: companies>, <Job: inside>, <Job: outside>]>
```

I want to iterate over them, and update their dict (merge their dict with a new dict) with a key that they don't have. Is it possible to do something like this?

```
for job in jobs:
   job.update('new_key' : 'new_value') #This returns error
```

To obtain the job object with the following keys: title, description, user, new_value.

Why do I want to do this? To be easier to iterate over those values that are correlated with jobs with only one for loop in the templates.

I don't want to use *Job.objects.all().values()* because that way I can't do *job.user.name* in the templates and get user name or user information.

Comment: This sounds a lot like annotations, with annotation you can add new "field" in queryset on db level [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset)

Comment: With a quick read I think that is it! Did not know that existed. Thank you!

Comment: If you do need to add this new attribute in a for loop (because you run some python logic to get that new value for example), remember that you're just dealing with python objects. That means you can do `setattr(job, 'new_key', 'new_value')`. And if you save to the db it will of course be ignored since it's not part of the schema

Comment: @Clepsyd can I do that when I make a query, or do I need to iterate over the queryset with a for loop and do it individualy?

Comment: @PedroSilva as i said this is a modification of the python objects (model instances) so you'll need to do that as you iterate over the queryset. If you want to do this at the database level then it's annotations as TrueGopnik suggested

Answer (score -1):

I did now and I got it. Use filter to take multiple ids. Use get only takes a single element. For example, if you have a queryset called Product with many products already registered, that is, with several id's. Do:

```py
a= list(Product.objects.filter(id=7)) 
b= list(Product.objects.filter(id__in=['3','5'])) 
a.append(b) 
print(a)
```